# How to use @SQLInsert with ResultCheckStyle.NONE in Grails to achieve Postgres partitioning

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, partitioning, database-partitioning

I want to use Grails with Postgres and partition a table.
I know, that Hibernate and Postgres is not the best pair when it comes to partitioning.
I've read [here (slide 25)](http://www.redhat.com/f/pdf/jbw/jmlodgenski_940_scaling_hibernate.pdf) that I can overcome the issue by using `@SQLInsert` with `ResultCheckStyle.NONE`.
I haven't been able to find anything like that in Grails. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer and created a sample project on github which covers it.
Also, it shows how to use Grails with partitioned Postgres table.

https://github.com/krstns/grailsPostgresPartitioning